# Can't create custom attributes in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create a custom attribute on Azure AD B2C, I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes), but when in the Azure AD B2C screen I can't see the User attributes option on the sidebar, it pops up while the page loads, but then quickly goes away.

This is just a development site I've got, and I believe I've got all permissions, what am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Link your directory to a subscription
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#create-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant